# springboot mongodb crud update only changed fields

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, upgrade, mongorepository

Hello i have springboot with mongodb (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb)

My problem is if I send only one or only the fields I want to change so the other values are set to null. I found something on the internet like @DynamicUpdate but not working on mongodb can you help me with this problem. I'm a beginner, I don't know how to help and it's quite important for me, if you need more code or more information, I'll write in the comment. I hope I have described the problem sufficiently. :)

MY POJO:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String note;
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository  extends MongoRepository <Person, String> {
}
```

i have this call

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public void UpdatePerson (@PathVariable String id , @RequestBody Person person) {
    personRepository.save(person);
}

@GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
public Person getPersonByid(@PathVariable String id ){
    return personRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(PersonNotFound::new);
}
```

sample:

get call before update :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Rambo",
    "lastName": "Norris",
    "enabled": true,
    "note": "hello this is my first note from you",
}
```

put call :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Chuck"
}
```

get call after update :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Chuck",
    "lastName": null,
    "enabled": false,
    "note": null,
}
```

what I would like

get call before update :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Rambo",
    "lastName": "Norris",
    "enabled": true,
    "note": "hello this is my first note from you",
}
```

put call :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Chuck"
}
```

get call after update :

```
{
    "id": "5fc940dc6d368377561dbb02",
    "firstName": "Chuck",
    "lastName": "Norris",
    "enabled": true,
    "note": "hello this is my first note from you",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **inserting** a new collection instead of **updating**. First, you need to get the **old value from mongodb**, then you need to **update the collection**, then **save to DB**.

Use the below code in `@putmapping`.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public void UpdatePerson (@PathVariable String id , @RequestBody Person person) {
    Person personFromDB = personRepository.findById(person.getId());
    personFromDB.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
    personRepository.save(personFromDB);
}
```

Comment: when i do this 

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public void UpdatePerson (@PathVariable String id , @RequestBody Person person) {
    Person personFromDB = personRepository.findById(person.getId());
    personFromDB.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
    personFromDB.setNote(person.getNote());
    .....
     personFromDB.setX(person.getX());
    personRepository.save(personFromDB);
}
```
and in request is 
```
{
    "id": "5fb5755603d57a5a3c9f6a63",
    "firstName": "Chuck"
}
```
then other like (note , lastName ..... , x  ) set them to null...

Comment: I can understand that the `person` object received `null` values(`lastName`, `note` etc) other than `FirstName`. You're setting all the values from `person` to `personFromDB` object, so you are null value saving other than `FirstName`. Check your `json` input request or post your `json` response here.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating like this

```
  @PutMapping("/{id}")  
  public ResponseEntity<Person> UpdatePerson (@PathVariable String id , @RequestBody 
  Person person) {

    Optional<Person> personData = personRepository.findById(id);
        if (personData.isPresent()) {
          Person _tutorial = personData.get();
          if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getFirstName())) {
         _tutorial.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
          }
          if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getLastName())) {
         _tutorial.setLastName(person.getLastName());
          }
          if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getNote())) {
         _tutorial.setNote(person.getNote());
          }
          if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(tutorial.isEnabled())) {
         _tutorial.setEnabled(tutorial.isEnabled());
         }
          return new ResponseEntity<>(repo.save(_tutorial), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
}
```